# Where to implement aggregate level permissions in DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, domain-driven-design

Assume I have an aggregate type of `Order`, which contains `OrderItems`. Depending on the state of an order, and the user-role operating on it, operations may be permitted or not permitted.

For example, if the user-role is `Customer` and the order's status is `Open`, then adding and removing items is permitted. Conversely, if the order's status is `Processing` then adding and removing items *is not* permitted. However, if the user-role is `Manager` and the order's status is `Processing` then adding and removing items *is* permitted.

My question is:

- Should the `Order` type handle these kinds of permissions? ie, it encapsulates all the logic about which roles can do what and therefore has a dependency on user-role.
- Or should this be handled outside of the `Order` type in a permissions service that would accept a role, an operation, and the subject of the operation (an order instance) and determine whether the action is allowed? ie, logic is externalized and assumed to be validated before the operation is executed on the `Order`, which has no knowledge of the concept of user-roles.

(Notes: The real-world use case is significantly more complex with large numbers of roles, statuses and actions. Authorization happens at an outer layer and has been applied already - this question is about instance specific permissions. In other words, a Customer is authorized to access the 'AddItemToOrder' API endpoint, but depending on the specific state of the order, the actual operation may or may not be allowed.)

Comment: Using something like `orderAuthorizationService.assertCanChangeItems(user, order)` in an application service seems simple enough? However, it seems like if you go down this path most business logic would end up buried in authorization rules. I'd most likely model 2 operations here as changing the items once the order is being processed is a different business process than changing items while the order has not yet been submitted. @guillaume31 answer is the way to go IMO. Another idea could be `addItem(Customer customer, ...)` and `addItem(Manager manager, ...)`.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to treat access control as applicative logic rather than domain logic, because not all domain operation calls will come from human users and need access control. Putting Permissions in a separate, cross-cutting layer or in a different Bounded Context also helps with Separation of Concerns.

In your example, I would try to come up with distinct domain method names for actions taken by a Customer and a Manager. Enriching the ubiquitous language can be a good arbiter when you're struggling with similar but slightly different concepts.

Comment: You make a good point about different modes of operating on an aggregate, and I agree that access control should sit outside. The nagging doubt for me is that whether an operation is permitted partially depends on the internal state of the aggregate, and exposing that state and making decisions externally feels like broken encapsulation.

Comment: My second point was precisely that there is not "an operation" that is permitted conditionally, but two operations - for instance, `AddItems()` (on an Open order) and `FixOrder()` (on a Processing order) :) This way you can control access more finely.

Comment: Yup I get that but it's not workable where there is effectively a large matrix of possible combinations given the number of states and number of roles. Encoding that into the methods themselves isn't practical, nor is there any domain language that adequately describes them.

Comment: i completly agree @guillaume31 . Also In enterprise application  we also create separate API and assign privilege of those API to each roles. There is one more thing we do that create a UserGroup with certain privileges and assign user in this and final Privilege check see if user can do the api or any UserGroup in which user is assigned

Answer (score 3):

In the current system I'm working on I solved this problem by creating overlays on my Domain-Objects. Most of my Domain-Objects start with interfaces, and I build different features with overlays.

For example:

```java
// Business-relevant features
public interface Order {
    ...
    void removeItem(Sku sku); // Or whatever
}

// Implementation  directly in the database, side-steps
// ORM problems, here off-topic, but belongs to example
public final class DatabaseOrder implements Order {
    ...
    public DatabaseOrder(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeItem(Sku sku) {
        connection.update(...);
    }
}

// This is the "authorization"
public final class AuthorizingOrder implements Order {
    private final Order delegate;
    private final User user;

    public AuthorizingOrder(User user, Order delegate) {
        this.user = user;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void removeItem(Sku sku) {
        if (user.isManager()) {
            delegate.removeItem(sku);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that is a simple example, but you get the point. In this solution there is no external, non-domain object, like a Service. Everything is tied into the Ubiquitous Language.

There are factories or builders that can plug these things together so at the end the system can work with `Order` objects that have all the necessary functionality even though they are cleanly separated.

Comment: Adding a decorator is quite a clean solution. From the example it suggests you're not using a repository? How would you pass your domain object back and forth through the repository? I would be tempted to only ever return the real aggregate and then overlay it explicitly where I need to ensure access control, then pass the delegate back to the repo for saving after performing any operations.

Comment: I mostly avoid any sort of "Repositories", since they are purely technical. I usually fit it inside business-relevant objects. For example there is no `getUser()` or `loadUser()`, there is only `login(...)` which returns a `User`. You can't decorate/overlay an object later, since you don't have the necessary information later to do it. You would have to "get" it from the object you overlay on, which would defeat the purpose of having a business-oriented interface.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of feel that you are relying on technical details rather than on a ubiquitous language. The ubiquitous language would already tell you what to do. But I assume you don't quite have such a language, or at least you have not hammered the user permissions through it, yet.

Here is my take on it, *assuming that you used the ubiquitous language when you asked your question*. Let's see where it takes us.

```
Given current User has Customer role
And Order status is Open and it has 1 Item
When User adds an Item to Order
Then Order should have 2 items
```

Here is how I model such a language (as a unit test for expressiveness):

```
//given.
var user = new User(role: new CustomerRole());
var order = new Order(status: OrderStatus.Open, items: new [] { new OrderItem(name: "Item 1", price: 1.00m });

//when.
order.AddItem(byUser: user, item: new OrderItem(name: "Item 2", price: 2.00m));

//then.
Assert.Equal(2, order.Items.Count);
```

So far, as we can see, the answer is somewhere inside `Order.AddItem` method. Most likely, inside it, you will have an expressive code like this:

```
public void AddItem(User user, orderItem item)
{
    if (user.Role.CanAddOrderItem() && this.Status.IsEqualTo(OrderStatus.Open))
    {
        this.items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Now we can see that it's determined by both the `Order` and `Role`. Again, assuming that this is how your ubiquitous language sounds.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is one option, the reason I'm wary of using it is because the Order type now has a dependency on User, also we always have to supply a User when adding an item. This may not always be the case.

Comment: I understand your concern.

Comment: However, I would rather think of dependencies as associations. If there is an association between order and user, there is nothing wrong in such code as well. Also, this may be not a user but a concrete type of user which the order depends on. I would suggest to define the bounded contexts and understand whether the user ends up in the same bounded context as the order. That should give much more clarity.

Comment: For the test, I would cover also unhappy scenario, and make sure that it is not any other side effect, which makes unhappy scenario fail. Ie. `given current user has customer role, and order is open; when user adds *valid item* to order; then order has got one more item` and  `given current user has customer role, and order is closed; when user adds *valid item* to order; then exception is thrown`,.. same for scenario without role,.. or, having different role, and so on,..